# How to stop black walnuts from hitting my roof without cutting branches?

Tags: roof, tree

My neighbors have a black walnut tree and late summer through fall the walnuts will fall and hit the roof of my house. Is there something I can put up, like a tarp or something, that could catch them?

[image: Side of House]
[image: Front of House]
[image: Size reference of Walnut]

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: What exactly concerns you? The sound of the nuts, possible impact damage or the accumulation of organic matter in the gutter? Textbook solution no.1 would be taking a view in your local law concerning trees from other properties.
The law often comes with surprisingly logical solutions for common problems. And "neighbors tree reaching in my property" is a common problem

Comment: Concerns are the possible damage that could come from the nuts impacting the shingles. Easy cleanup of the nuts would also be a benefit but for that I could just put netting from the fence line to the house.

Comment: You would want an expert to do any trimming, but free nuts outside the backdoor sounds like a bonus.  A roof should take walnuts falling on it, but a tarp/net should not hurt.

Comment: @StephenGilboy I can assure you with complete certainty that tree will never grow tall enough for the walnuts to gain enough speed to do any damage to your roof.  I can imagine that will become an issue for gutter maintenance though.  As for local laws, if you are in the us (and likely almost anywhere else in the world) you can remove any part of the tree crossing your property line with or without permission from your neighbor.  So you can have a tree company lop off any branches over your property line to help prevent them from accumulating in your gutter.

Comment: This even includes the main trunk of the tree, if it leans over onto your property halfway up they can cut the entire top of the tree off.

Comment: @jesse_b, I have to disagree. While you won't see individual divots, the granular surface of the shingle is being degraded by the impacts. When the granules go away the shingle fails, and I'd be willing to bet that there's more loose granule coming off the side of the roof with walnuts falling on it. Over the years this has an effect. Whether that's worth worrying about is a matter of opinion. (I'd also be curious about the basis for your "absolute certainty". Have you done a scientific study?)

Comment: @isherwood The granules coming off in itself is not ideal but also not necessarily damage.  When inspecting for hail damage you look for spots where the granules have been removed because that spot has seen an impact strong enough to destroy the integrity of the shingle below.  However simply walking on a roof displaces granules as well but does no damage to the shingle.  Most studies agree that it takes hailstones greater than 1" to do any damage to an asphalt shingle and a 1" piece of ice traveling at terminal velocity has orders of magnitude more energy than these walnuts traveling ~10 mph

Comment: I knew you were coming from a hail damage/insurance adjuster standpoint. Long-term damage is a different issue and insurance claim standards don't apply. I know _with absolute certainty_ that walking does indeed do damage. I've seen roofs over which siding was installed with significant damage. I see damage where I normally access my roof for various maintenance tasks, even though I'm very careful about shoe choice and foot position. These things are undisputable to a long-term homeowner and former builder.

Comment: @isherwood that is actually not what I said though, the granules are not required at all for the structural integrity of the shingle.  The only reason adjusters look for them being removed in an isolated spot is because that indicates a point of concentrated damage.  The granules mostly exist to prevent the shingles from sticking together in transport and for cosmetic reasons, also one of their purposes is literally to provide a safe walking surface for people to work on the roof without slipping off.

Comment: @StephenGilboy, this is a difficult question to answer because it's open-ended and it's subject to your constraints and preferences regarding cost, aesthetics, convenience, etc. I'd look at putting up netting, if anything. A tarp would be a sail and you'd need robust support.

Comment: @jesse_b, no. They wouldn't use expensive ceramic if that was true. You're wrong on several points here. (I was installing shingles in the 80s and selling them in the 90s and installing them again in the 2000s. You aren't making a strong case.)

Comment: @isherwood The granules do provide some durability so I suppose I partially agree with your argument that over time it could add up to what would be considered "significant" damage however again the shingle will perform perfectly fine with zero granules on it.  I can say with certainty that it would never get to that point though because I'm familiar with shingles, the life of the roof, the physics of falling objects, and I grew up with two walnut trees in my yard.  The fruit around the walnut is relatively soft and the whole thing is very light, and they don't have room to fall fast.

Comment: Given the sound those make hitting the ground, I certainly don't want to be hit by one. Your roof? Less clear, but having that main branch over you house trimmed seems a fairly easy thing to do.

Comment: Do you really want a tarp over your roof? IMHO, that looks terrible, like you're neglecting maintenance or a major leak, just to avoid a little bit of wear on the shingles. Walnuts should roll off the roof on their own, but you might want some gutter guards or foam inserts to block accumulation.

Comment: Black walnuts are the most delicious nuts.   You should smile to hear the sounds.  Tough as hell to get the meat out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the walnuts will damage the roof, as they have a cushion layer. There is a netting material used to keep birds out of fruit trees etc. It is black and hard to see when viewed at a distance. Attaching that would be a way to keep them from hitting your roof. You would need to stretch it enough so they roll off when hitting the net. My concern would be that installing a net or tarp would cause more damage th the house then the walnuts over the next decade. The wind can also remove them.

Comment: The problem with netting is that it will also catch leaves, and then it's not so hard to see when viewed at a distance.